# Scalability of S3 Upload and S3 Download

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

So, we are uploading to S3 and dowloading from S3.
When we test with different bandwidths the upload scales pretty good, consumes somewhere 70-80% of bandwidth.

But in case of download, it does not scale. It uses hardly 30-40% of the bandwidth.
We tried listing and downloading and directory download as well.
Both replicate same behavior.

Can someone please help in understanding why downloading from S3 is not scaling ?

Comment: There could be a range of reasons really. Are you downloading to your local machine or within AWS?

Comment: When we tried within AWS the download speed increased. But comparing scaling on both within and to local system, it didn't improved only in case of download.